# Taobao API - isv.permission-api-package-empty

Tags: php, api, yii, categories

I'm new with Taobao API and I'm not Chinese. I need to obtain category list and items from Taobao.com.

I'm using Yii and this extension: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/topsdk4yii/

I have Api key and Api Secret, I'm trying to make a query and a receive this error:

```
object(stdClass)[16]
 public 'code' => int 11
 public 'msg' => string 'Insufficient isv permissions' (length=28)
 public 'sub_code' => string 'isv.permission-api-package-empty' (length=32)
```

I make query in this way ( in SiteController.php -> function actionIndex() ):

```
Yii::import('application.extensions.taobao.request.*');
    $request = new ShopGetRequest();
    $request->setNick('my_username_from_taobao');
    $request->setFields('sid,cid,title,nick,desc,bulletin,pic_path,created,modified');
    $shop = Yii::app()->top->execute($request);
    var_dump($shop);
```

I found some explanation here http://open.taobao.com/support/question_detail.htm?id=496 but I can't find how to fix this.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can't fix it from your application

you have to tell to the Api owner to **white-list your server ip address** if not done your application will not be able to make requests to taobao api.

Comment: I have the API Owner account, I added my server ip to white-list, but don't works.

Comment: @Simer I didn't found a solution. Project was abandoned.

Answer (score 1):

The error means your application has not applied for the required permissions. You can do this from the application menu (providing an explanation of the application plus reason for applying in Chinese), after which they will handle your application within 3 working days.